# JS: Which end am I closer to when clicking element

Tags: javascript

I apologies in advance if there is a simple answer to this, my excuse is that i'm ill and can't think straight right now!

Basically I have got an array of elements, which correspond to a range slider with 2 handles, basically 2 range sliders over-layed.

```
Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
 [0]     [1]      [2]      [3]     [4]     [5]     [6]
  x                                 x
```

We pass the index of the day of the week to the function, which of course is 0-6.

What I want to do is click one of the days of the week, and then get which range (min/max) slider is closer to that value. So using the example above, clicking **Thursday** would mean that the right **x** is closer.

Clicking **Tuesday** will mean the first **x** is closer, so then I can change the corresponding data accordingly.

Didn't show any code as it won't really help, as this is more of a Math issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Well calculate the absolute of the difference for each, and take the minimum of that?

Comment: Maybe something like this will work.
`(num)=>Math.min(4-num,num-0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `left` and `right` are ints from 0-6 representing the days the Xs are on, and `day` is the number of the day clicked:

```
function nearestDate(left, right, day) {
  const compare = (day - left) - (right - day);
  if (compare === 0) {
     // they're equidistant;
  } else if (compare < 0) {
     // left one's closer
  } else {
     // right one's closer
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on thanks, I did try it like this as I did think it was the way, but must of gone wrong somewhere! Expected the `-1` on my post, an explanation from whom put it would be nice! hjaha

Comment: @MartynBall wasn't me but probably because your question includes no attempt or any code and therefore is off topic as it is too broad - if it is truly a math problem and not a coding one, you should have posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/